# How do I structure my Android Studio project to avoid compilation issues with running the app with unit tests integrated

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, robolectric

I am running the latest version of Robolectric, Android Studio, and Gradle.

As the title suggests ever since I worked on Robolectric test cases, I am having a hard time switching back to app and making the android app compile like it used to be.

Every time I try to run the app, I get the following compilation errors:

```
Error:(35, 23) error: package org.robolectric does not exist
Error:(36, 23) error: package org.robolectric does not exist
Error:(37, 34) error: package org.robolectric.annotation does not exist
Error:(38, 42) error: package org.robolectric.shadows.httpclient does not exist
Error:(44, 2) error: cannot find symbol class Config
Error:(43, 10) error: cannot find symbol class RobolectricTestRunner
Error:(197, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable FakeHttp
Error:(198, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable FakeHttp
Error:(218, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable FakeHttp
Error:(238, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
Error:(250, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
Error:(260, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
Error:(263, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
Error:(275, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
Error:(291, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
Error:(294, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
Error:(305, 32) error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
Error:(317, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable Robolectric
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
    sourceSets{
            main {

                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                java.exclude {'src/test'}
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
            test {
                java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
            }

            // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
            // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
            // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
            // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
            // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
            // by a similar customization.
            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')      
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/KochavaSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/adobeMobileLibrary-4.11.0.jar')
    compile project(':cardview')
    compile project(':CropImage')
    compile project(':MapboxAndroidSDKNew')
    compile project(':android-pdfview')
    compile project(':UserVoiceSDK')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.+'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
    compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }

    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.1.2'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-httpclient:3.1.2'

}
```

For the current file structure, I have set the test and com.example.application folders underneath the src folder, which was causing these compilation issues.

I am aware that there are some work arounds for this fix, which consists of excluding the test folder by using 'java { exclude 'src/test'}' under the main sourceset, but I tried that and it didn't seem to work. I also tried to add compile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2' and other robolectric libraries needed, but it's gotten too bothersome and now I need to set this project up properly to where I can achieve this desirable effect.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Reworded this question a little better.

Comment: Try making your question more specific i.e: How do I better structure my project to avoid, issue 1,issue 2, issue 3. Otherwise people won't be sure what to answer with.

Comment: Where do you run your app?

Comment: @kyle I just reworded my question a bit. It should be better

Comment: @EugenMartynov I am running the latest version of Android Studio and Gradle

Comment: the `java.exclude {'src/test'}`  like is saying to exclude everything since `{}` indicates a Closure. try changing it to `java.exclude 'test/**'`

Comment: @Aarjav holy shit. I can't believe that worked. Pardon the french, but I have been focusing on this for too long and your answer finally solved the problem. Could you please put your comment as your answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `java.exclude {'src/test'}` in the `sourceSets` block to `java.exclude 'test/**'`

The original way was calling exclude with a [`Closure` argument](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html#exclude(groovy.lang.Closure)), a closure which always returned true, which meant exclude everything.

you may also want to pair it with `java.include '**/*.java'` (before the exclude) and `resources.exclude '**/*.java'` in the future. Not sure what your build is like but tasks like [`processResources`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) may change because of it.